# How to use useRef to get element to use react-scroll to ensure smooth page transition

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

I was trying to build a website that is just one single page, with a navbar using different elements.
(Something akin to the example website given in [this example](https://www.turnwall.com/articles/adding-single-page-scrolling-navigation-to-your-site/)) however in react instead of native Javascript.

So far I have a `NavBar.tsx` and `App.tsx`, where
`NavBar.tsx` is

```js
import { Button, Link } from 'react-scroll';
import React from 'react';
import { Link as RouterLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useRef } from 'react';

export interface NavBarProps {
    events?: string;
    team?: string;
    sponsors?: string;
    contact?: string;
    corporate?: string;
}

export default function NavBar(props: NavBarProps) {

    let myRef: Array<HTMLDivElement> = [];

    const saveRef = (ref: HTMLDivElement) => {
        myRef.push(ref);
    }

    return (
        <ul className="w-full sticky top-0">
            <li>
                <Link className="link inline float-right p-5 hover:bg-yellow-400 text-white" id="navBar"
                    activeClass="active" to={props.events} spy={true} smooth={true} offset={-70} duration={500}
                    ref={saveRef}>
                    Events
                </Link>
                <div ref={saveRef}>
                    <Link className="link inline float-right p-5 hover:bg-yellow-400 text-white" id="navBar"
                        activeClass="active" to="projects" spy={true} smooth={true} offset={-70} duration={500}
                        ref={saveRef}>
                        Our Team
                    </Link>
                </div>
                <div ref={saveRef}>
                    <Link className="link inline float-right p-5 hover:bg-yellow-400 text-white" id="navBar"
                        activeClass="active" to="blog" spy={true} smooth={true} offset={-70} duration={500}
                        ref={saveRef}>
                        Sponsors
                    </Link>
                </div>
                <div ref={saveRef}>
                    <Link className="link inline float-right p-5 hover:bg-yellow-400 text-white" id="navBar"
                        activeClass="active" to="contact" spy={true} smooth={true} offset={-70} duration={500}
                        ref={saveRef}>
                        Contact Us
                    </Link>
                </div>
                <div ref={myR}>
                    <Link className="link inline float-right p-5 hover:bg-yellow-400 text-white" id="navBar"
                        activeClass="active" to="section1" spy={true} smooth={true} offset={-70} duration={500}
                        >
                        Corporate
                    </Link>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    )
}
```

(This is just for testing so far hence some information may be different between different links. Also, the class names are so long because I'm using Tailwind).

I was using link to make sure that when the navBar is clicked, the page takes you to the right element.

However, I am not sure how would I change this to make the website with smooth scrolling(again like in the website but instead of a side navbar, I have a top navbar).

My `App.tsx` basically just has 4 sections which the Links point to, and while some youtube videos and websites like those I linked were helpful, I'm not sure how do I import them over to React Typescript. I saw react-scroll was helpful but I wasn't sure how to use those with Link from react-router-dom.

Thank you and I'll be glad to provide any more information about my project.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve smooth scroll with a ref you can do something like this

```
const elementRef = useRef(null);

const onClick = () => {
  elementRef.current.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'});
}
```

Unfortunately the smooth behaviour is not supported across all browsers so you will need to install `smoothscroll-polyfill`